# Accelerate processing Low Poly by Renderscript

Tags: java, android, bitmap, renderscript

### What is Low Poly?

[Low Poly wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_poly)

### Delaunay

I implemented the `Delaunay` Algorithm  in java; but its very slow. In my pc, processing a bitmap to low poly takes about 4-9 seconds. And is **Much worse** in android mobile. It takes about 1-2 min even *if* I resize the input bitmap.

### Implementation

```
 final class Delaunay {


private static int[][] supertriangle(List<int[]> vertices) {
    int xMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int yMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int xMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int yMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    float dx, dy, dmax, xmid, ymid;


    for (int i = vertices.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int[] p = vertices.get(i);
        if (p[0] < xMin) xMin = p[0];
        if (p[0] > xMax) xMax = p[0];
        if (p[1] < yMin) yMin = p[1];
        if (p[1] > yMax) yMax = p[1];
    }

    dx = xMax - xMin;
    dy = yMax - yMin;

    dmax = Math.max(dx, dy);

    xmid = (xMin + dx * 0.5f);
    ymid = (yMin + dy * 0.5f);

    return new int[][]{{(int) (xmid - 20 * dmax), (int) (ymid - dmax)},
            {(int) xmid, (int) (ymid + 20 * dmax)},
            {(int) (xmid + 20 * dmax), (int) (ymid - dmax)}};
}

private static Circumcircle circumcircle(List<int[]> vertices, int i, int j, int k) {
    int x1 = vertices.get(i)[0];
    int y1 = vertices.get(i)[1];
    int x2 = vertices.get(j)[0];
    int y2 = vertices.get(j)[1];
    int x3 = vertices.get(k)[0];
    int y3 = vertices.get(k)[1];


    int fabsy1y2 = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
    int fabsy2y3 = Math.abs(y2 - y3);

    float xc, yc, m1, m2, mx1, mx2, my1, my2, dx, dy;


    if (fabsy1y2 == 0) {
        m2 = -((float) (x3 - x2) / (y3 - y2));
        mx2 = (x2 + x3) / 2f;
        my2 = (y2 + y3) / 2f;
        xc = (x2 + x1) / 2f;
        yc = m2 * (xc - mx2) + my2;
    } else if (fabsy2y3 == 0) {
        m1 = -((float) (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1));
        mx1 = (x1 + x2) / 2f;
        my1 = (y1 + y2) / 2f;
        xc = (x3 + x2) / 2f;
        yc = m1 * (xc - mx1) + my1;
    } else {
        m1 = -((float) (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1));
        m2 = -((float) (x3 - x2) / (y3 - y2));
        mx1 = (x1 + x2) / 2f;
        mx2 = (x2 + x3) / 2f;
        my1 = (y1 + y2) / 2f;
        my2 = (y2 + y3) / 2f;
        xc = (m1 * mx1 - m2 * mx2 + my2 - my1) / (m1 - m2);
        yc = (fabsy1y2 > fabsy2y3) ?
                m1 * (xc - mx1) + my1 :
                m2 * (xc - mx2) + my2;
    }

    dx = x2 - xc;
    dy = y2 - yc;

    return new Circumcircle(i, j, k, xc, yc, (dx * dx + dy * dy));
}

private static void dedup(ArrayList<Integer> edges) {
    int a, b, m, n;
    for (int j = edges.size(); j > 0; ) {
        while (j > edges.size()) {
            j--;
        }
        if (j <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        b = edges.get(--j);
        a = edges.get(--j);

        for (int i = j; i > 0; ) {
            n = edges.get(--i);
            m = edges.get(--i);

            if ((a == m && b == n) || (a == n && b == m)) {
                if (j + 1 < edges.size())
                    edges.remove(j + 1);
                edges.remove(j);
                if (i + 1 < edges.size())
                    edges.remove(i + 1);
                edges.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static List<Integer> triangulate(final List<int[]> vertices) {
    int n = vertices.size();

    if (n < 3) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    Integer[] indices = new Integer[n];

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        indices[i] = i;
    }


    Arrays.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
            return vertices.get(rhs)[0] - vertices.get(lhs)[0];
        }
    });
    int[][] st = supertriangle(vertices);

    vertices.add(st[0]);
    vertices.add(st[1]);
    vertices.add(st[2]);

    ArrayList<Circumcircle> open = new ArrayList<>();
    open.add(circumcircle(vertices, n, n + 1, n + 2));

    ArrayList<Circumcircle> closed = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> edges = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        int c = indices[i];

        for (int j = open.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            Circumcircle cj = open.get(j);
            int[] vj = vertices.get(c);

            float dx = vj[0] - cj.x;
            float dy = vj[1] - cj.y;

            if (dx > 0 && dx * dx + dy * dy > cj.r) {
                closed.add(cj);
                open.remove(j);
                continue;
            }


            if (dx * dx + dy * dy - cj.r > 0) {
                continue;
            }

            edges.add(cj.i);
            edges.add(cj.j);
            edges.add(cj.j);
            edges.add(cj.k);
            edges.add(cj.k);
            edges.add(cj.i);

            open.remove(j);
        }

        dedup(edges);

        for (int j = edges.size(); j > 0; ) {
            int b = edges.get(--j);
            int a = edges.get(--j);

            int x1 = vertices.get(a)[0];
            int y1 = vertices.get(a)[1];
            int x2 = vertices.get(b)[0];
            int y2 = vertices.get(b)[1];
            int x3 = vertices.get(c)[0];
            int y3 = vertices.get(c)[1];

            boolean hasCircumcircle = true;
            if ((x1==x2)&&(x1==x3) || ((y1==y2)&&(y1==y3))){
                hasCircumcircle = false;
            }
            if (hasCircumcircle) {
                open.add(circumcircle(vertices, a, b, c));
            }
        }

        edges.clear();

    }

    for (int i = open.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        closed.add(open.get(i));
    }

    open.clear();

    ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <closed.size(); i++) {
        Circumcircle ci = closed.get(i);
        if (ci.i < n && ci.j < n && ci.k < n) {
            out.add(ci.i);
            out.add(ci.j);
            out.add(ci.k);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

private static class Circumcircle {
    public int i, j, k;
    float x, y, r;

    public Circumcircle(int i, int j, int k, float x, float y, float r) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.k = k;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Circumcircle){
            Circumcircle circumcircle = (Circumcircle) obj;
            if (x==circumcircle.x && y==circumcircle.y && r==circumcircle.r)
                return true;
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}


}
```

### Delaunay Library in C

[delaunay](https://github.com/eloraiby/delaunay)

This library is written in C. So I think it's faster than java.

### My problem

I want to use `RenderScript` to acclerlate the processing.How can I input some points and get triangles (just indices of the input points)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary:** You should at least try the C version to see how effective it is.

RenderScript is about parallelizing problems so that many different worker units either on CPU or GPU can process the data. What this implies though is that the algorithm that you want to implement in RenderScript must minimize loops and conditionals. Just looking at the code above shows a number of loops and if statements which in my mind doesn't port well to RenderScript.

A quick search shows a number of academic papers on parallelizing Delaunay, so while it is possible you would have to research what would make sense for your input set or what would be acceptable tradeoffs.

Comment: Have you seen the C  library?

Comment: I looked at the link. I was suggesting to either try to port the library or your own code into C and make that work in Android JNI.